# A silent, risky riddle

Tags: riddle, mystery

> I have the perfect figure.
>
> I show off in the internet.
>
> When people say I'm anorexic, it leaves me with...

**<sub>Who, or *WHAT* am I?</sub>**

Hint 1:

> What do you lose when you are shamed?

Hint 2:

> I'm a legend!

Hint 3:

> I'm white.

Hint 4:

> I'm tall and male.

Hint 5:

> I dress like a gentlemen.

Comment: Boi, this needs a lot of hints...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the hints I think the answer might be

> [Slender Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slender_Man)

I have the perfect figure.

> I guess "slender" is something people aim for.

I show off in the internet.

> Originated as and continues to be an internet meme

When people say I'm anorexic, it leaves me with

> no face

Hints,

> A tall, white man, dressed smartly matches the description. It is also a myth (legend) and has no face (lose face when you are shamed).

Comment: It's rot13(Jura crbcyr fnl V'z naberkvp, vg yrnirf zr jvgu ab snpr.). I left out the rot13(ab snpr) because I thought that way it would be too obvious. Looks like I shouldn't have, so to spare all those other hints.